# N best list of Alternates in SAPI Command and Control Mode

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I am using Speech Recognition Engine(in-proc) in Command and Control mode for my application. At many times, I am getting incorrect result and no other alternates to the suggested result.

I wanted to know if number of alternates being returned by SAPI are governed by some parameter? I already know about the MaxAlternates property of the engine. What I mean is that, are there any parameters that govern the number of alternates being "generated" by the recognizer? For example, does the Engine only allow alternate results which are over a particular threshold value of Confidence?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a minimum confidence level for alternates.  The SR engine builds a markov model from the grammar, and you can only get alternates if there's a feasible path through the model that results in more than one path through the grammar.

As a (rather contrived) example, if your grammar has "red" and "blue", and you say "green", you're likely to get a 'no recognition' event, as there's really no path from the phonemes that maps to anything in the grammar.

if you have "red" and "head", and you say "bed", then there's a possibility for alternatives, as there's a feasible path through the model that could encompass more than one path in the grammar.